# Thunderbird mail notification filter

Tags: macintosh, thunderbird

I have a secure mail account, which is only configured on one machine and it needs to stay that way. I've been looking for a solution to receive a notification of a new message without the need to log on to this machine and check it manually.

The easiest solution I could come up with is to create a filter, which would send an email (to another account) simply stating that there's new mail.

Unfortunately Thunderbird (out-of-the-box) supports only message forwarding, which obviously would defeat the purpose of having a secure account.

Is there any solution or plugin that would help me with that?

Comment: You could install some kind of script that reads the pop box, just the headers, and then sends an alert if a new mail has arrived. I guess this doesn't make it less secure as it can run on the same machine.